# Initialising a KeyValuePair Array

Tags: c#, arrays

This seems like a straightforward thing to do, but I don't seem to be able to work out the correct syntax.  I currently have this:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] kvpArr = new KeyValuePair<string,string>[];
```

However, this seems to work:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] kvpArr = new KeyValuePair<string,string>[10];
```

But I don't know the size of the array initially.  I know I can use a list of KVPs and I probably will, but I just wanted to know how / if this could actually be done.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a `Dictionary`...or is this a theoretical question about initialization of arrays?

Comment: It is a theoretical question - but I will also have duplicate entries.

Comment: If you want lookup functionality and you need to handle multiple values per key, you could consider using the System.Linq.Lookup<T> class. It's immutable though. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't do this - because an array always has a fixed size. If you don't specify that size to start with, what size would you expect to be used? You *either* have to specify the size itself *or* the contents (which allows the size to be inferred). For example:

```
int[] x = new int[10]; // Explicit size
int[] y = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // Implicit size
int[] z = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // Implicit size and type
```

`List<T>` is definitely your friend for collections where you don't know the size to start with.

Answer (score 14):

Arrays are fixed-size by definition. You can either specify the size as in your second code example, or you can have it inferred from the initialization:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>[] kvpArr = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(...),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(...),
    ...
}
```

If you want a variable length structure, I suggest you use the `List<T>`.

For more information about arrays, see the [C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx).

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon :)

Answer (score 7):

Why not rather use

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
```

Have a look at [List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var kvpArr = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
```